# What is the Grooviest way to implement an incrementing integer list?

Tags: data-structures, groovy

I need a data structure which is a list of integers but each time an integer is added to it the value it stores is the sum of the values it contains plus the value that is added.

For example:

```
def incrementingList = []
incrementingList.add(5) // now it has 5
incrementingList.add(3) // now it has 5,8
incrementingList.add(2) // now it has 5,8,10
```

Is there a groovy way to implement this so it can be ready to use as in the example?

**UPDATE**

What if it is possible for this list to contain 0s and if the last element is a 0 then it should increment by the last non 0 element?

Comment: you shouldn't change the semantic of a method like 'add', it's easy to have a lot of explainable bugs with such a thing. give it an explicit name!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use metaprogramming to define custom method:

```
List.metaClass.plusAdd = { e ->
    delegate.isEmpty() ? delegate.add(e) : delegate.add(delegate.last() + e)
}

def l = []
l.plusAdd(5)
l.plusAdd(3)
l.plusAdd(2)
assert l == [5, 8, 10]
```

**EDIT**

Update for adding last non-zero element:

```
List.metaClass.plusAdd = { e ->
    if(delegate.isEmpty()) {
        delegate << e
    } else {
        def nonZeros = delegate.findAll { it > 0 }
        delegate << (nonZeros ? nonZeros.last() + e : e)
    }
}

def l = []
l.plusAdd(5)
l.plusAdd(3)
l.plusAdd(2)
assert l == [5, 8, 10]
l = [5, 0]
l.plusAdd(5)
assert l == [5, 0, 10]

l = [1,0]
l.plusAdd(5)
assert l == [1, 0 ,6]
```

Comment: could you suggest how solution can be tweaked based on my update?

Comment: Will have a look on tomorrow?

Comment: that would be great, much appreciated friend.

Comment: Yes that is right, sometimes while running it I get NoSuchElementException: Cannot access last() element from an empty List

Answer (score 2):

this should be simple and working

```
 incrementingList.add(incrementingList.last() + 5)
```

check if not empty:

```
incrementingList.add((incrementingList.size() > 0 ) ? incrementingList.last() + 5 : 5)
```

,

```
​def incrementingList = []
incrementingList.add((incrementingList.size() > 0 ) ? incrementingList.last() + 5 : 5)
incrementingList.add((incrementingList.size() > 0 ) ? incrementingList.last() + 5 : 5)
incrementingList.add((incrementingList.size() > 0 ) ? incrementingList.last() + 5 : 5)
println incrementingList​
```

output:

```
[5, 10, 15]
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different approach:

```
def addToList(incList, val) {
    if (incList.size() > 0) {
        incList << incList.last() + val
    } else {
        incList << val
    }

    return incList
}

def incList = []

addToList(incList, 3)
addToList(incList, 2)
addToList(incList, 5)

println incList
```

output:

```
[3, 5, 10]
```

**Updated**:

```
def addToList(incList, val) {

    if (incList.size() > 0) {
        if (val != 0) {
            incList << val + incList.last()
        } else {
            def addVal = incList.size() > 1 ? (incList[-1] - incList[-2]) : incList[-1]
            incList <<  addVal + incList.last()
        }
    } else {
        incList << val
    }
}

def incList = []

addToList(incList, 5)
addToList(incList, 3)
addToList(incList, 0)
addToList(incList, 5)
addToList(incList, 0)

println incList
```

output:

```
[5, 8, 11, 16, 21]
```

Comment: could you suggest how solution can be tweaked based on my update?

Comment: @AbuMariam: My updated version should fit your need.

Comment: Thanks @Roland, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion, based on the update request (as I understand it)...

[Edit: the 'empty' case is covered by the 'no non-zero' case, so it can be simplified]

```
List.metaClass.addAsSum = { e ->
    def nonZero = delegate.reverse().find { it != 0 }

    if (nonZero != null) {
        delegate.add(nonZero + e)
    } else {
        delegate.add(e)
    }
}
```

Test runs:

```
def list

// test 0
list = []
list.addAsSum(5)
assert list == [5]

// test 1
list = []
list.addAsSum(5)
list.addAsSum(3)
list.addAsSum(2)
assert list == [5, 8, 10]

// test 2
list = []
list.addAsSum(5)
list.addAsSum(3)
list.addAsSum(0)
list.addAsSum(2)
assert list == [5, 8, 8, 10]

// test 3
list = []
list.addAsSum(0)
list.addAsSum(0)
list.addAsSum(0)
list.addAsSum(2)
list.addAsSum(4)
assert list == [0, 0, 0, 2, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a requirement that on a list filled only with zeros it should simply add the new element, this is my suggestion:

```
List.metaClass.fill = { n ->
    delegate ? delegate.add((delegate.reverse().find { it > 0 } ?: 0) + n) : delegate.add(n)
    delegate
}

assert [].fill(1).fill(2).fill(3) == [1, 3, 6]
assert [5, 0].fill(5) == [5, 0, 10]
assert [0, 0].fill(5).fill(5) == [0, 0, 5, 10]
```

note that I return delegate in the fill() such that you can call it in sequence.